# NSNumber as key for NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c

I was wondering how keys work in a NSDictionary.  Usually, I will use a NSString as a key for example:

```
NSString *stringKey = @"stringKey";
[mydict objectForKey:stringKey];
```

What if I wanted to use a NSNumber:

```
NSNumber *numberKey = [NSNumber numberWithInt:3];
[mydict objectForKey:numberKey];
```

Does the dictionary go look for the key with number 3?  or would it just compare the address of the numberKey?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two keys are equal if and only if `[key1 isEqual:key2]`.  Some classes may go with the `-[NSObject isEqual:]` implementation of `return self == other;`, but it's quite common for classes (such as `NSString`, `NSNumber`, etc) to override it to do more context-specific comparison.

Comment: The [`-hash`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html) is important as well when determining the equality of objects.

Comment: @Joe `[key1 hash] == [key2 hash]` is only guaranteed to be true iff `[key1 isEqual:key2]`.  Thus, if the 2 keys are equal, you know that their hashes must be equal as well.  However, equal hashes does *not* imply equal objects.  (for more info, check out the `-[<NSObject> hash]` documentation)

Comment: I am aware that `hash` does not imply equality and may have been poor wording choices saying "determining equality". It was more of note to the OP that `hash` is important especially in the more context-specific cases that you mention (NSString etc). I am also aware that you know the purpose of the `hash` function :)

Comment: For a detailed description on how to properly implement isEqual: and hash, see http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html

Comment: @DaveDeLong So, two different instances of `NSNumber` created with the exact same value (e.g., 3.2f) will be treated as equivalent when used as dictionary keys? Will `-setObject:forKey:` replace an existing entry, or always create a new one? Your answer doesn't seem to give a definitive answer to that question.

Comment: Forget it; I tested it in code and it seems that different-but-arithmetically-equivalent instances of `NSNumber` yield the same dictionary key (which makes sense).

Answer (score 3):

I think it will look at the value of NSNumber. i use NSNumber as key for dictionary.

### 1. store the key in view.tag

view.tag = [self getUniqueNSIntegerKey];  --> get a unique key and save in view.tag

[dictionary setOjbect: object forKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:view.tag]]; // add the object

### 2. retrieve the object with the view.tag later

object = [dictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:view.tag]]; // get the object via view.tag

it just works.....