# NSNumber swift Dictionary to userdefaults swift3

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber

I am trying to save swift dictionary `[NSNumber : NSNumber]` to UserDefaults. I have already tried to cast it as NSDictinonary, but still, the application crashes when I use set() function.

Key is a beacon minor key (NSNumber)
Value is an `NSTimeinterval` cast as `NSNumber`

the crash:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

```
var  recentBeacons: [NSNumber : NSNumber] = [:]

func saveRecentBeaconDict()
{
    let recentBeaconKeys = recentBeacons.keys
    print("keys type is \(String(describing: recentBeaconKeys.self))")

    let recentBeaconsNSDict = recentBeacons as NSDictionary
    UserDefaults.standard.set(recentBeaconsNSDict, forKey:"recentBeacons")
}
```

> prints out: keys type is LazyMapCollection< Dictionary < NSNumber, NSNumber >, NSNumber >(_base: [46171: 1501585588.173543], _transform: (Function))

Comment: share some code that you tried.

Comment: What is the exception reason?

Comment: @vadian the exception reason is right there in the O.P.'s original question, above the source.

Comment: I am thinking the ultimate problem is because either the keys or the values are ***not*** the types the O.P. think they are.  Try doing something like `let recentBeaconKeys = recentBeacons.keys ; 
print("keys type is \(String(describing: recentBeaconKeys.self))")`" and tell me what types the keys (or values) really are.
`

Comment: @MichaelDautermann No, that's the message that an exception occurred but it doesn't contain the **reason**.

Comment: AS I try to insert same dictionary to Userdefaults I got the error as below `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object {
    0 = 123;
    1 = 456;
    2 = 789;
} for key dict'`

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I have updated the O.P.

Comment: Apart from the issue you are strongly discouraged from using a floating point type (here `Double`) as dictionary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below answer.

```
    var  recentBeacons: [NSNumber : NSNumber] = [:]
    func saveRecentBeaconDict()
    {
        let archivedObject = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: recentBeacons as NSDictionary)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: "recentBeacons")

        let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "recentBeacons") as? Data
        if let _data = data {

            let allData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: _data) as! NSDictionary
            print(allData)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't save Dictionary of type [NSNumber : NSNumber], allowed only [String, AnyObject] or [NSObject : AnyObject].

As approach you can convert your `NSNumber`'s to `String`'s

Comment: [I believe you ***can*** use NSNumbers as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337811/nsnumber-as-key-for-nsdictionary), Taras.  You might be thinking of raw C types, like `ints`.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann yes, you can use `NSNumber` as key of `Dictionary`, but you can't use  `[NSNumber : NSNumber]` as object for `NSUserDefaults`